# Escaping quotation marks in a bash script on macOS

Tags: macos, bash, script, escape-characters

I want to turn the following command:

`$ gdate --date='TZ="America/New_York" 1am' +"%a %F %H:%M %Z"`

into a script using parameters, such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
gdate --date='TZ="$1" $2' +"%a %F %H:%M %Z"
```

but it doesn't work due to need for proper quotation mark escaping.

I'm struggling to work out the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The shell does not do variable substitution in single quotes, but substitution works in double quotes.  So you need to turn the first argument into a double quoted string like so:

```
gdate "--date='TZ=\"$1\" $2'" +"%a %F %H:%M %Z"
```

I put the first argument in double quotes and then escape the inner double quotes so they pass through this round of shell.

You can put a `set -x` above this in your script to see what is getting substituted before the command gets executed.

Comment: I'm afraid there's a clash between `gdate` escaping reqirements and shell's: `gdate: invalid date ‘'TZ="America/New_York" 1pm'’`